# i need my animation before to end ,start again(marquee)

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, marquee

i make a train animation for news, similar slider, i need before the last animation show start again animation , this code first show animation start to end and when finish start again but i need after 4s start again ,
when i use animation-delay , first show text for 4s  and after start animation

here is my link in codepen

https://codepen.io/soodeh/pen/RmEgmp

```
<div class="containerb" id="listone">
    <ul>
       <li class="train" id="one">
           aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
       </li>
       <li class="train" >
           bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
       </li>
       <li class="train" id="three">
           bccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
       </li>
       <li class="train" >
           dddddddddddddddddddddd
       </li>
   </ul>    
</div>

// css styles     
.containerb {
    padding-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}    
.containerb .train {
    /*width: 100px;*/
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    animation: train 30s infinite linear ;
    -webkit-animation: train 30s infinite linear;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
}
#one{
    background: yellow;
}
#two {
    background: blue;
}
#three {
    background: green;
}
#four {
    background: red;
}

@keyframes train {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
    }    
    50% {
        left:0%;
    }    
    100% {
        left: -100%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes train {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
    }    
    50% {
        left: 0%;
    }    
    100% {
        left: -100%;
    }
}
.containerb   ul{
    width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called `marquee`

Comment: This has a simple example: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa